# Hide text field and display message for Delivery checking

Tags: php, magento-1, product-view, delivery

please visit this link : http://hotwheelstoys.in/mobileapp2/funny-pets-wonder-teddy-1802.html

there is an option to enter the zip code and check there is

"delivery available or not to that zip code".

once we entered the zip code and click on  "check" button, it will display

the paticular message below the text field.

but once we entered the pin code and clickon "check" button, i want to hide the text field and want to display the message as like

: http://www.flipkart.com/peacock-basic-architect/p/itmdzdt44rzemzjf?pid=BLCDCYYHKPY9UVMG&ref=L%3A7578364719676933414&srno=p_1&query=peacock&otracker=from-search

we are using this code : http://pastebin.com/t6y6vyQe

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have hide the delivery zipcode block. So on the AJAX success function you have to write the code to hide the `div`

```
$('block_info').hide();
```

before that use `<div id="delivery-html">` and `<div id="delivery-message">` outside of the `<div id="block_info">`

Now if the customer want to change the `zipcode`

So add the `<a>` after the `<div id="delivery-html">` and use the below script

```
Event.observe('delivery-pincode-change', 'click', function(event){
         $('block_info').show();
         $('delivery-message').hide();               
         $('delivery-html').hide();
});
```

You can use [this code](http://pastebin.com/bZ7P0prx)

Comment: i changed the code, but still not working ,what else i have to do ?

Comment: i can't see the changes here http://hotwheelstoys.in/mobileapp2/funny-pets-wonder-teddy-1802.html

Comment: use this http://pastebin.com/s8bqxckQ

Comment: please check now, i used your code.....

Comment: check this http://pastebin.com/bZ7P0prx

Comment: still the same problem.....

Comment: try this code http://pastebin.com/TeZHqqyJ

Comment: i dont know what to say for you..... thanks a lot bro.....